COUNT(DISTINCT <col>) without GROUP BY
In Django, Count("col", distinct=True) can be used to perform COUNT(DISTINCT col) but it automatically adds a GROUP BY so is there a way to prevent that from happening so the distinct count of all rows that match the WHERE can be received?
